# css select element when sibling appears

Tags: html, css

Hello i have structure:

```html
<section class="entry">
  <div class="1">
     <div class="IappearSometimes">text1</div>
     <p class="ImAlwaysShowingText">text2</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

I would like to hide by `display:none` p class .ImAlwaysShowingText element, only when div class .IappearSometimes appears. 
By default class .ImAlwaysShowingText is always on screen and i want to hide it when class .IappearSometimes shows on. 
I was trying by nth-child, ~ selector, but after 2 days of trying its hiding other elemtns on page, im really lost.. 
Can I select it somehow?

Comment: If they are adjacent siblings, `.IappearSometimes + .ImAlwaysShowingText { display: none; }`..

Comment: Josh Crozier solved my case. Thank You very much guys for help!

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```css
.IappearSometimes ~ .ImAlwaysShowingText {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<section class="entry">
  <div class="1">
     <div class="IappearSometimes">text1</div>
     <p class="ImAlwaysShowingText">text2</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Edit: You can see here **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/390/)** if `.IappearSometimes` exists `.ImAlwaysShowingText` will have `display: none`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it through jQuery

```
if  ($('.IappearSometimes.').is(':visible')) {
    $('.ImAlwaysShowingText').hide();
}
```

This will cause when element `IAppearSometimes` is visible on screen to hide `ImAlwaysShowingText`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is enough (combined selector):

```
.IappearSometimes.ImAlwaysShowingText {
  display: none;
}
```

EDIT: Sorry, no space in between the classes.
Here's a codepen (with another line added): http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pgybdL